# Python3 StopIteration Error can not raise when using list(map(...))

Tags: python, python-3.x, stopiteration

At first I write this, and it raises StopIteration, works well.

```
it = iter([1])
iters = [it] * 2
for it in iters:
    r = next(it)
    print(r)
```

but when I changed to this:

```
it = iter([1])
iters = [it] * 2
r = list(map(next, iters))
print(r)
```

It can not raises StopIteration, How to explain this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`list` constructor detects that the argument is an iterable, so it iterates on it a bit like this (I'm making this up):

```
def __init__(self,iterable):
    # some init stuff to create the list
    while True:
       try:
           next_element = next(iterable)
           self.append(next_element)
       except StopIteration:
           break
```

At some point the iterable raises `StopIteration`, so `list` intercepts it and ends the list (it has no other way to do so with generators, the exception is the signal that indicates that the iteration has ended)

Same as:

```
list(map(next,iter([])))
```

here, the exception is propagated from a level below. `map` is not raising it, but `next` is. For `list` constructor, which is catching the `StopIteration` exception, it doesn't make a difference which level raises it.

And yes, there's no way you can let `StopIteration` "escape" from the `list`  constructor, but you can get this raised with a list comprehension:

```
r = [next(it) for it in iters]
```

(since `iters` is the one getting watched for `StopIteration`, not `map`, so you have found a case where `list(map(f,y))` isn't the same as `[f(x) for x in y]`)